# Is it possible to use Websockets/Socket.IO with cellular data/4g?

Tags: node.js, react-native, websocket, socket.io, 4g

I am making React Native App which requires constant connection between the clients and server. The app works only when using wifi. Has anyone managed to get this sort of thing working with Socket.IO? Or any other alternatives such that it works with cellular data? Why exactly does this work with wifi but not with cellular data?


Here is my code for connecting to the server running on my PC on port 3000:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('...'); // http://ip:3000
export default socket;
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Cellular data is about connecting you to internet using any mobile access technology 3G/4G/5G. Once you have 3G or 4G sign on your device screen, mobile network has already assigned you one IP address among one of available internal subnets and you are ready to go. Your Wifi modem is router at the same time and it allows to you reach another IP from same subnet. Using mobile data you can not do that, because now you are the part another big local area network which can not access private IP address assigned by you WIFI router.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working by hosting my server and Postgres database using Heroku and then connecting to it. Wasn't working because I was trying to connect to a private IP address (192.168.1.254) which only works when connected to the same Wifi.